# Allocate memory for dynamic array of structures inside a structure with double pointer**

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management, struct

When I use this code I would like to turn to every element of array of structures like this:

```
array[0]->X;
array[1]->X;
```

I tried everything I could, but in all cases I've had Segmentation fault. What am I doing wrong?

Please look at blocks between #if 0 #endif

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

typedef struct
{
    double X;
    double Y;

} ArrayOfStructures;

typedef struct
{
    uint_fast64_t length;

    ArrayOfStructures **array;

} Points;

typedef struct
{
    Points *points;

} Config;

void add_new_array(Config *conf)
{
    printf("conf=%p\n",conf);
    printf("conf->points=%p\n",conf->points);
    printf("conf->points->length=%zu\n",conf->points->length);
    printf("conf->points->array=%p\n",conf->points->array);
    #if 0
    ArrayOfStructures *temp = (ArrayOfStructures*)calloc(conf->points->length,sizeof(ArrayOfStructures));
    printf("temp=%p\n",temp);
    // Segmentation fault
    *conf->points->array = temp;
    #else
    conf->points->array  = (ArrayOfStructures **)calloc(conf->points->length,sizeof(ArrayOfStructures *));
    #endif
    printf("conf->points->array=%p\n",conf->points->array);
}

void another_function(Config *conf)
{
    conf->points->length = 1;

    add_new_array(conf);

    conf->points->array[0]->X = 0.1;
    conf->points->array[0]->Y = 0.2;

    printf("The result: X=%.12f, Y=%.12f, length=%zu\n",conf->points->array[0]->X,conf->points->array[0]->Y,conf->points->length);
}

void some_function(Config * conf)
{
    // To pass the structure to another function
    another_function(conf);
}

int main(void)
{
    // Stack's allocated memory
    Config conf_;
    Config *conf = &conf_;
    memset(conf,0x0,sizeof(Config));

    // Stack's allocated memory
    Points points;
    memset(&points,0x0,sizeof(Points));
    conf->points = &points;

    some_function(conf);

    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Compiled using:

```
gcc -D_SVID_SOURCE -g -ggdb -ggdb1 -ggdb2 -ggdb3 -O0 -DDEBUG -std=c11 -Wall --pedantic arryay.c -o array
```

I tried to find answers for handling a double pointer, but everything is very confusing.

Comment: Are you trying to create a dynamic array of structures, which would require `ArrayOfStructures *array` and `array[0].X`, or a dynamic array of pointers to structures (which uses the pointer to pointer notation, but isn't what the title suggests you're after)?

Comment: Good question. Seems to me, It doesn't matter how turn to an element of a structure array[0]->X; or array[0].X; I would like to use fastest way to access of all these elements, because high performance is important to me.

Comment: Double pointers (pointers to pointers, that is) require two memory accesses to get at the data; single pointers require one.  You should probably go with the simpler version, then.

Comment: Also, don't hide multiple statements on a single line, as in `Points points; memset(&points,0x0,sizeof(Points)); conf->points = &points;`.  Use one line per statement.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I would like to create a dynamic array of structures, not a dynamic array of pointers to structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're fairly close to what you want according to your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56450254/allocate-memory-for-dynamic-array-of-structures-inside-a-structure-with-double-p?noredirect=1#comment99495336_56450254).

#### Using array of structures

Here's an adaptation of your code.  The primary change is use `ArrayOfStructs *array` instead of using a pointer-to-pointer.  Also, because you've decided to use `uint_fast64_t` for a data type, you have to use `PRIuFAST64` from `<inttypes.h>` to get the correct format string.  It would be better to change that to `size_t`; you aren't going to spot the performance difference on any reasonable system (but the code uses the format `PRIuFAST64`).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

typedef struct
{
    double X;
    double Y;
} ArrayOfStructures;

typedef struct
{
    uint_fast64_t length;
    ArrayOfStructures *array;
} Points;

typedef struct
{
    Points *points;
} Config;

static
void add_new_array(Config *conf)
{
    printf("conf=%p\n", conf);
    printf("conf->points=%p\n", conf->points);
    printf("conf->points->length=%" PRIuFAST64 "\n", conf->points->length);
    printf("conf->points->array=%p\n", conf->points->array);

    ArrayOfStructures *temp = calloc(conf->points->length, sizeof(ArrayOfStructures));
    printf("temp=%p\n", temp);
    conf->points->array = temp;
    printf("conf->points->array=%p\n", conf->points->array);
}

static
void another_function(Config *conf)
{
    conf->points->length = 1;

    add_new_array(conf);

    conf->points->array[0].X = 0.1;
    conf->points->array[0].Y = 0.2;

    printf("The result: X=%.12f, Y=%.12f, length=%" PRIuFAST64 "\n",
           conf->points->array[0].X, conf->points->array[0].Y, conf->points->length);
}

static
void some_function(Config *conf)
{
    // To pass the structure to another function
    another_function(conf);
}

int main(void)
{
    // Stack's allocated memory
    Config conf_;
    Config *conf = &conf_;
    memset(conf, 0x0, sizeof(Config));

    // Stack's allocated memory
    Points points;
    memset(&points, 0x0, sizeof(Points));
    conf->points = &points;

    some_function(conf);

    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

When run, this produces:

```
conf=0x7ffeed6883f8
conf->points=0x7ffeed688400
conf->points->length=1
conf->points->array=0x0
temp=0x7fef13c02a80
conf->points->array=0x7fef13c02a80
The result: X=0.100000000000, Y=0.200000000000, length=1
```

It doesn't crash.  I've not run it under [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).  It will report leaks for the allocated memory.

Your type name `ArrayOfStructures` for a type that has no array in it seems wildly inappropriate.  I'd've expected that to be given a name such as `Point`.  I assume your `Config` structure has been minimized for this question (if so, thank you).  If not, then the structure holding a single pointer to another structure is not giving you any benefit.  It is just slowing down your access to the data — vastly outweighing any benefit from using `uint_fast64_t` instead of `size_t`.  You'll need to be careful about your allocation of memory for the `Config` structure; you can't simply free everything inside the `Config` and its child structures at the moment.

#### Using array of pointers to structures

This is very similar to the last code, but you need an extra set of memory allocations.  I've made that into a loop since the only reason for using this design is to allow you to allocate the pointed at structures separately.  Otherwise, it is just needlessly complex.  I've made a few minor cleanups; there are more improvements possible.  I've added a structure dumper function, `dump_points()`, which I can and do use to print values at different points.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

typedef struct
{
    double X;
    double Y;
} ArrayOfStructures;

typedef struct
{
    size_t length;
    ArrayOfStructures **array;
} Points;

typedef struct
{
    Points *points;
} Config;

static void dump_points(const char *tag, const Points *points)
{
    printf("%s (%zu, %p)\n", tag, points->length, (void *)points);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < points->length; i++)
        printf("%zu: (%.12f, %.12f) %p\n", i, points->array[i]->X, points->array[i]->Y,
               (void *)points->array[i]);
}

static
void add_new_array(Config *conf)
{
    printf("conf=%p\n", (void *)conf);
    printf("conf->points=%p\n", (void *)conf->points);
    printf("conf->points->length=%zu\n", conf->points->length);
    printf("conf->points->array=%p\n", (void *)conf->points->array);

    conf->points->array = calloc(conf->points->length, sizeof(conf->points->array[0]));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < conf->points->length; i++)
        conf->points->array[i] = calloc(1, sizeof(conf->points->array[i][0]));
    printf("conf->points->array=%p\n", (void *)conf->points->array);
    printf("conf->points->array[0]=%p\n", (void *)conf->points->array[0]);
    dump_points("Inside add new array", conf->points);
}

static
void another_function(Config *conf)
{
    conf->points->length = 3;

    add_new_array(conf);

    conf->points->array[0]->X = 0.1;
    conf->points->array[0]->Y = 0.2;
    conf->points->array[1]->X = 1.1;
    conf->points->array[1]->Y = 1.2;
    conf->points->array[2]->X = 2.1;
    conf->points->array[2]->Y = 2.2;

    dump_points("Inside another function", conf->points);
}

static
void some_function(Config *conf)
{
    // To pass the structure to another function
    another_function(conf);
    dump_points("Inside some function", conf->points);
}

int main(void)
{
    // Stack's allocated memory
    Config conf_;
    Config *conf = &conf_;
    memset(conf, 0x0, sizeof(Config));

    // Stack's allocated memory
    Points points;
    memset(&points, 0x0, sizeof(Points));
    conf->points = &points;

    some_function(conf);
    dump_points("Inside main", conf->points);

    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Sample output (macOS 10.14.5 Mojave; GCC 9.1.0):

```
conf=0x7ffee6f6b408
conf->points=0x7ffee6f6b410
conf->points->length=3
conf->points->array=0x0
conf->points->array=0x7f9c0a402a70
conf->points->array[0]=0x7f9c0a402a90
Inside add new array (3, 0x7ffee6f6b410)
0: (0.000000000000, 0.000000000000) 0x7f9c0a402a90
1: (0.000000000000, 0.000000000000) 0x7f9c0a402aa0
2: (0.000000000000, 0.000000000000) 0x7f9c0a402ab0
Inside another function (3, 0x7ffee6f6b410)
0: (0.100000000000, 0.200000000000) 0x7f9c0a402a90
1: (1.100000000000, 1.200000000000) 0x7f9c0a402aa0
2: (2.100000000000, 2.200000000000) 0x7f9c0a402ab0
Inside some function (3, 0x7ffee6f6b410)
0: (0.100000000000, 0.200000000000) 0x7f9c0a402a90
1: (1.100000000000, 1.200000000000) 0x7f9c0a402aa0
2: (2.100000000000, 2.200000000000) 0x7f9c0a402ab0
Inside main (3, 0x7ffee6f6b410)
0: (0.100000000000, 0.200000000000) 0x7f9c0a402a90
1: (1.100000000000, 1.200000000000) 0x7f9c0a402aa0
2: (2.100000000000, 2.200000000000) 0x7f9c0a402ab0
```

It's reassuring to see that the data is not corrupted as it is passed back up the chain of functions.

Comment: Thank you very much for working example. You are right, real code has been minimized for this question. I left in its original form the entire tree of function calls and nesting of structures, simplifying everything else. Valgrind my everyday's  tool and I have no problem to free memory. But pointers and its dereferencing sometime makes me cry )

Comment: Well, I understood my mistake. However, I wonder how this code should look with a dynamic array of pointers to the structure?

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much again. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to initialize `length` to a meaningful value. Therefore you don't actually allocate memory, since you call `calloc()` with the first argument being zero.

(Disclaimer: I haven't tested the code, but that seems to be wrong.)

Comment: Uninitialized length is my fault. Unfortunately I can't change  the text of source code, because this site have a bug. But if you try to add conf->points->length = 1; at the begin of another_function() call nothing will be change. Segmentation fault stay the same.